# How do I change a UIViewController with one tap in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I put this in my `ViewController1` class but the code returned an error:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    let vc: ViewController2 =  ViewController2(nibName: "ViewController2", bundle: nil)
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle > (loaded)' with name 'ViewController''

Comment: Have you `ViewController2` on your storyboard?

Comment: I'm not using storyboard, I would like to do this programmatically.

Comment: and you don't have the associated nib file for this viewController?

Comment: I not created a nib for the first viewcontroller.

Is there a way to do this programmatically without xib or storyboard ?

Comment: Thanks CeceXX. That was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't a second `UIViewController` on your Storyboard, instantiate one and present it. I've turned the `backgroundColor` of the `secondViewController` to red so you can actually see the transition between the views.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

    let secondViewController = UIViewController()
    secondViewController.view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```